# Windows Restart Manager doesn't see folders opened by the command prompt as in use

Tags: windows, winapi, command-prompt, restartmanager

When using the [Restart Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc948910%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), if I add a path to [RmRegisterResources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373663%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that is currently opened as the current working directory in a command prompt window, [RmGetList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373661%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) doesn't return it, but instead returns info about other locked files (e.g., an executable loaded in WinDBG).

Why is that so?

If I try to delete this folder, I get an `error 32: ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION`, which is why I used the Restart Manager to identify the processes that are preventing me from deleting files and folders.

Comment: Are you sure that `RmRegisterResources()` supports folder paths to begin with? Everything I have read about it only mentions files, not folders.

Comment: Ha! Good point... I didn't think about that... Thanks!